# UIScrollView will not zoom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios6

I have a subclassed `UIView` which I can get to scroll but not to zoom. I'm using autolayout so wondered if anything had changed in IOS6. In particular when are the `scrollViewWillBeginZooming` and `scrollViewDidEndZooming` methods implemented. My code looks like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.ringSet2 = [[RingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 800)];
    [self.ringSet2 setDefaults];

    /// ... more setup for other views but only ringSet2 is scrolled.

    self.scrollview1.delegate=self;
    self.scrollview1.scrollEnabled=YES;
    self.scrollview1.contentSize=self.ringSet2.bounds.size

    self.scrollview1.minimumZoomScale=0.2;
    self.scrollview1.maximumZoomScale=5.0;

    self.ringSet2.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    // ... needed elsewhere so other views can pick up their dimensionts 

    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    /// ... code for additional views

    [self.scrollview1 zoomToRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200) animated:YES];
    [self.scrollview1 addSubview:self.ringSet2];

}
```

with

```
-(UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    return self.ringSet2;
}
```

and `scrollViewWillBeginZooming` etc. implemented just to trace what is happening. Interesting, 
`viewForZoomingInScrollView` appears to get called only once, as is `scrollViewDidEndZooming` with  a scale value just under one but `scrollViewWillBeginZooming` is never called. The property ringSet2 is defined

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet RingView *ringSet2;
```

as the view does not appear if it's defined as weak.

Comment: Makes sense that the view doesn't appear: You are responsible for retaining top level objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologises for this. The answer is really stupid. I'm currently developing under IOS 6.0 on the simulator whilst my phone is still on IOS 5. The simulator allows you to simulate pinches but only centred on the centre of the screen. The scrollview however only receives this signal if it too is in the centre which was not the case in my initial build. Moving the scroll view's rectangle into the centre fixed the problem. You would not make this mistake testing on a real device. The code is thus OK. Lost 3 or 4 evenings pulling my hair over this one.